# A web page with dropdown field with large data content does not display data to the user through Microsoft web proxy server

Tags: web, server, https, drop-down-menu, proxy

I have a IIS web server behind a Microsoft Web Proxy Server using HTTPS tunneling. When a user access a web page containing a dropdown field the data within the dropdown does not show if the chosen field in the dropdown has large amount of data to display, but the same dropdown shows that data if the data is lot less.

Any help will be very appriciated!

Thank you!

My developer says he uses a post in the web server to send data to the Web proxy server.

1. I logged in to Windows Web Proxy Server as an administrator and accessed the website and logged to my account in it. then accessed the faulty dropdown page and picked the field in the dropdown which does not work outside the Web proxy server. to my surprise, the dropdown shows all the data within the web proxy server; however, when I access the same dropdown field from outside of the web proxy server dropdown field does not display any data.

But if I pick the field in the dropdown which has less data content then data is displayed.

Why dropdown field with large data content does not shows the data outside Web proxy server using HTTPS.

2. If I removed the Certs from the website then all the dropdown display all data from any chosen field in the dropdown from outside of the Web Proxy Server??

3, I also gave more memory to the web Proxy server to eliminate any resources cruch if any but the problem persists.